# Facing issue in setting up oozie with secure MapR cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, oozie, mapr

We are facing an issue with setting up an oozie service with secure mapr cluster.

We are using the MapR installer to setup the MapR Cluster. Below are the configuration and steps that we followed.

MapR version - 6.1

Os - Ubuntu 16.04

Authentication - Kerberos

Nodes - Single node

1. We have enabled the Mapr security by using the **`Enable Secure Cluster`** option in the installer.

Reference doc - https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/61/AdvancedInstallation/using_enable_secure_cluster_option.html

2. We have installed the kerberos in the machine.

Reference doc - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kerberos-kdc-server-and-client-on-ubuntu-18-04

3. Below are the commands we executed to setup kerberos authentication for the MapR cluster

Reference docs -
https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/61/SecurityGuide/Configuring-Kerberos-User-Authentication.html
https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/61/SecurityGuide/ConfiguringSPNEGOonMapR.html

```
sudo kadmin.local
addprinc -randkey mapr/my.cluster.com
ktadd -k /opt/mapr/conf/mapr.keytab mapr/my.cluster.com

addprinc -randkey HTTP/<instance-name>@<realm-name>
ktadd -k /opt/mapr/conf/http.keytab HTTP/<instance-name>@<realm-name>

addprinc -randkey mapr/<instance-name>@<realm-name>
ktadd -k /opt/mapr/conf/mapr2.keytab mapr/<instance-name>@<realm-name>

sudo chown mapr:mapr /opt/mapr/conf/mapr.keytab /opt/mapr/conf/http.keytab /opt/mapr/conf/mapr2.keytab
sudo chmod 777 /opt/mapr/conf/mapr.keytab /opt/mapr/conf/http.keytab /opt/mapr/conf/mapr2.keytab

ktutil
rkt /opt/mapr/conf/mapr.keytab
rkt /opt/mapr/conf/http.keytab
rkt /opt/mapr/conf/mapr2.keytab
wkt /opt/mapr/conf/mapr.keytab

sudo /opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -N my.cluster.com -C <CLDB Node>:7222 -Z <ZookeeperNode>:5181 -K -P "mapr/my.cluster.com@<realm-name>"
```

**Note:
The command which is mentioned in the doc (`configure.sh -K -P "<cldbPrincipal>"`) throws error , but the above command works.**

```
kinit
maprlogin kerberos
hadoop fs -ls
```

3.1 ) We are able to access the mapr file system.

3.2) We are using the below command to run a simple mapreduce job and it works fine.

```
hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.0-mapr-1808.jar pi 16 1000
```

4. Oozie configuration with kerberos authentication
   Reference doc - https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/61/Oozie/ConfiguringOozieonaSecureCluster.html

We have added below properties in the oozie-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.type</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
    <description>
    Defines authentication used for Oozie HTTP endpoint.
    Supported values are: simple | kerberos | #AUTHENTICATION_HANDLER_CLASSNAME#
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.keytab.file</name>
    <value>/opt/mapr/conf/mapr.keytab</value>
    <description>
      Location of the Oozie user keytab file.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>local.realm</name>
    <value>{local.realm}</value>
    <description>
      Kerberos Realm used by Oozie and Hadoop. Using 'local.realm' aligns with Hadoop configuration
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>mapr/<hostname>@${local.realm}</value>
    <description>
       Kerberos principal for Oozie service.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>HTTP/<hostname>@${local.realm}</value>
    <description>
      Indicates the Kerberos principal to be used for the HTTP endpoint. The principal MUST start with 'HTTP/' per the Kerberos HTTP SPNEGO specification.
    </description>
</property>
```

5. We are checking the oozie status by using  `bin/oozie admin -status -auth KERBEROS`  command , we are getting below error.

**java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 1. Exception = Could not authenticate, Authentication failed, status: 302**

Kindly help us to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Oozie is a frigging nightmare in general. Adding Kerberos won't make it easier. Just saying.

The issue that you are describing appears to be that some component isn't getting the memo about the Kerberos identity that you are using or doesn't have access/permissions to validate an access. This is a common problem and typically requires step-by-step interaction to work through what is known and what is not yet known (but often is assumed). I am definitely not an expert on these kinds of issues, however.

You have a really excellent problem report here which is exactly the sort of thing that the support team can use.

Do you have an active support or partner in place?

Comment: Hey Ted, Thanks for your comments. We have an active partner , but no help from them on this issue.

Comment: We should go direct on this. You can find my contact information out there in the wild. Use any email, linked in or twitter address you find.